# Firebase auth signing out user instantly

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm not sure if this is a problem with my means of displaying react components depending on if a user is signed in or if it a problem with how I'm handling the user auth with firebase. Basically, as soon as a user signs in, they are brought back to the login page before even being able to view the proper page to land on. Here is my code for handling the display of the auth page

```
class Portal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      user: {},
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.authListener()
  }

  authListener = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ user })
        console.log(user)
      } else {
        this.setState({ user: null })
        console.log(user)
      }
    })
  }

  loginHandler = (username, password) => {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password).then(() => {
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
    })
  }

  logoutHandler = () => {
    firebase.auth().signOut()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.user ?
          (<PortalMain
            logoutHandler={this.logoutHandler}
          />) :

          (<Login
            loginHandler={this.loginHandler}
          />)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Portal
```

Comment: Can you show the output of the `console.log(user)` statements in your code, both before and after you sign in?

Comment: Also, do you have a redirect setup on you `PortalMain` component and/or do you have private routes set up with a router?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the console is actually refreshing on submit and leaves no trace of the console log. The page is clearly refreshing but I'm not entirely sure why since I'm only displaying a component contingently based on the data.

Comment: @JoshPittman the only thing that may be causing an issue like that is my logout function but if I disable the login form altogether I can confirm the logout function isn't being called when the component is rendered.

Comment: If the page refreshes it sounds like a [submit handler is not canceling the default behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event#Examples). It's hard for me to say how to precisely fix it, without seeing what the `Login` component does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resides with the browser auto-refreshing on form submit. I fixed the problem by adding `event.preventDefault()` to the beginning of my submit function.

Comment: Can you please tell me exactly where and how? I am facing the same issue and am very new to react.